# How to generate new columns in phpexcel

Tags: php, mysql

I want to generate columns to match the displayed data on the web page then download excel sheet format from web page. Using PHPEXCEL to download the mysql data to excel format.

```
while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()){

     while($loops = $sqlStudent->fetch_assoc()){

    //problem is here, i want to generate more column to match the web page data displayed      

    //I want to generate four groups of colums for 1 row
    // this code show below must repeat x5 with different column letters.
      $sheet->getActiveSheet()
          ->SetCellValue('G'.$rowCount, $loops['section_1'])
          ->SetCellValue('H'.$rowCount, $loops['section_2'])
          ->SetCellValue('I'.$rowCount, $toto)
          ->SetCellValue('J'.$rowCount, $grade);

          }
     $rowCount++;
}
```

Picture show results from mysql, I want to generate that result to excel format.

I try to generate excel sheet by I fail to iterate that shaded columns shown on picture below.

[image: img]

Any idea to solve this problem guys, I appreciate any help in order to slve this problem.